# Parse and extract image URL file names based on specific alt tags

Tags: php, html, parsing, xpath, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to print out a list of image file extensions within a webpage excluding the .png extension.

I only want to parse all image file names from image url's within a website that use **div class = cartoon** only.

**Example Structure:**

```
<div class="cartoon">
<img src="URL/images/element8/12345.png" alt="cartoon">
```

**Desired Output**: 12345

Here is my code that I use to return all images

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('URL'); 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodelist = $xpath->query("//img"); // find your image
$imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with PHP, but it seems there is the same inside `$nodelist` and `$imageTags`? Why would you have both? What is your problem with that code? What does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it with xpath?
How about:

```
.//*[contains(@class, "cartoon")]//img[not(contains(@src, "png"))]
```